# How do you specify the FullyQuailifiedName in an Item Query via the QuickBooks-online API SDK

Tags: api, sdk, quickbooks-online

We have a test C# VS2013 web program that works somewhat based on the SDK sample.

We are having an issue in trying to Query via the FullyQualifiedName (i.e. Major:Minor).

```
Select * From Item WHERE Name = '" + pItemName + "' MaxResults 1
```

works but

```
Select * From Item WHERE FullyQualifiedName = '" + pItemName + "' MaxResults 1
```

fails with the `ValidationException`.

This is true for `pItemName = 'Test' or 'Major:Minor'`.

Can someone please tell me how to code the query for a FullyQualifiedName?

Answer (score 0):

According prod docs, this field is filterable. 
Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/item

It looks like a bug in service. I've informed this to dev team. I'll update this post asap.

**Request**
select * from Item where FullyQualifiedName='Item_1af77Test4'

**Respose**

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2013-12-23T23:04:41.421-08:00">
  <Fault type="ValidationFault">
    <Error code="4001">
      <Message>Invalid query</Message>
      <Detail>QueryValidationError: Property FullyQualifiedName not found for Entity Item</Detail>
    </Error>
  </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

**EDIT**
As of now, you can't use this **FullyQualifiedName** as a filterable attribute. Confirmed.

Thanks